# How to display object properties dynamically in reactjs list view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Iam trying to render a list view from json object. Here object properties are dynamic we cant predict everytime it loads what kind of properties it might get.

Scenario1:

```
let foo = {
    bar: 'Hello World',
    baz: 'How are you doing?',
    last: 'Quite alright'
};
```

Scenario2:

```
let foo = {
    abc: '123',
    xyz: 'timestamp string format'
};
```

I tried this with plain javascript, 
but how to make this with reactjs list view?
will foo.map() works or is there any alternative approach for this ?

```
for (var key in foo) {
  console.log(key+' : '+foo[key]);
}
```

View to achieve(Table)

```
bar  | helloworld
baz  | how are u doing
last | Quite alright
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: it depends on how are you trying to render. Can you also include your render code and how you plan to render the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would recommend is to use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(foo).map(key => 
    <li key={key}>{key} | {foo[key]}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

This allows you to do what you want without having to manipulate your current object.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the React docs on [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

```
const listItems = Object.values(foo).map((x, i) =>
  <li key={i}>{x}</li>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ul>{listItems}</ul>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: but we are not able to access the key name here, only value is getting display

Answer (score 0):

There may have multiple way to do that. I think this is the most straight forward one.

```
 <ul className="my-list">
      {Object.values(foo).map((myFoo, i) =>
         <li key={i}>{myFoo.key} | {myFoo.value}</li>
      )}
 </ul>
```

Comment: @Srinivas map is a function of array, not object. You can convert your object to an array with `Object.values(foo)`

Comment: thank you @nnyby, i missed that. first need to convert into array. then we can access with this.